# datacrawler with HtmlAgilityPack not working properly

Tags: c#, web-crawler

```
foreach (HtmlNode item in html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='list-road']//ul[@class='melding']"))
            {

                string[] traject = item.SelectSingleNode("//li[@class='locatie']").InnerText.Split(new string[] { "Van " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

Hello, I made a datacrawler with the HtmlAgilityPack in C# but I have a problem. I loop over lists. When I print the value of the storing it is different on every iteration as it should be. The problem is that when I use the SelectSingleNode method, I always get the value of the first storing.

Comment: by design `SelectSingleNode` selects first node

Comment: But the storing variable in my foreach is different on every iteration. I use that variable with the SelectSingleNode.

Comment: var uItems=html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='list-road']//ul[@class='melding']");

foreach (HtmlNode item in uItems)
            {

                string[] traject = item.SelectSingleNode("//li[@class='locatie']").InnerText.Split(new string[] { "Van " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
}

probably you should check it out as workaround.